# Why isn't blood pink in the Future Arc (Mirai-hen), like it is on other Danganronpa media?

Tags: danganronpa

In the first *Danganronpa* anime series (2013), [blood is pink to prevent the series from having to have a higher age rating](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4403/49).

In *Danganronpa 3: The End of Kibougamine Gakuen - Zetsubou-hen* (2016), the "*Despair Arc*," blood is also pink:

[image: Punching a wall will make you bleed]

The first time blood was seen in *Danganronpa 3: The End of Kibougamine Gakuen - Mirai-hen* (2016), the "*Future Arc*," the setting was pretty dark, so I wondered whether that made the blood not look pink or if it was actually not pink. In episode 5, we get a clear view of red blood, though:

[image: Avoid stabbing your eye with rebar, or you'll bleed too]

[image: Jon Snow is not in Danganronpa, no.]

Given that the "*Future Arc*" is set after all the events in the other pieces of the franchise, [is it possible that something changed in-universe](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/why-is-blood-pink-in-danganronpa#comment48723_4403)? Or does the "*Future Arc*" air at a different time, which makes the rating not as important for the producers of the show?

[Someone in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/danganronpa/comments/4ujumv/dr3_spoilers_i_just_realized_why_blood_is_red/) suggests that it's only so the gag with the tomato sauce in the third episode, when pretending Asahina had been killed, is possible — that's obviously (?) not the case, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on a theory from Japanese audiences ([source](http://danganronpa.net/archives/sb225.html)), the pink blood is only shown on school life/game (class trial) setting (e.g. DR1 and DR2).

> 学生じゃないからじゃね
> Isn't it because they are not students already?
>
> 学級裁判とは違ってゲームじゃないって事じゃね？
> Isn't it because it's different from class trial game?

As for personal theory extending from this theory, it has something to do with *school life → age → "censoring"*. Now that they have graduated (or *"matured"*) in DR3:Future, the blood is shown red, just as real life.

---

<sup>Note: however, [some blood is (or looks like) pink in Future's OP scene](http://danganronpa.net/archives/sb128.html).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The blood is pink to show that Despair arc is more of a slice-of-life, but future is more gore and gritty. This is also shown in the OP for Despair being in pastel colours, but the OP of Future being dark.